# How setup lauch.json for VS Code so I can use other folders/files in the current working directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write python code that needs to read files in the same current working directory. I'm new using VS code so I don't really know how to set it up have the `launch.json` the following way, but it still doesn't read other files in the same cwd. HELP :'v

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[${cwd} - the task runner's current working directory on startup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

The default setting of 'cwd' is the "${workspaceFolder}". In VSCode, the relative path depends on the setting parameter 'cwd', unless you use an absolute path. It doesn't care the relative path to your python file, it just cares the relative path to 'cwd'.